# Firefox entity/special character text shown instead of Special Character glyph

Tags: fonts, character, special-characters, font-face

I am trying to use a [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/) font I compiled and have run into a problem on Firefox not displaying the character but instead showing a stacked text of that entity.

Say the character is `&#xe004;` which can be written many different ways such as:

```
&#57348; &#xe004; 
```

It will display as tiny print that would fit in a single character:

```
E0
04
```

Here is what it looks like in Chrome vs Firefox:

[image: Chrome and Firefox issue preview]

**Demo** of where I am trying to use the font on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/GSYMk/). It is just a custom checkbox demo.

I realize that the demo doesn't work in IE because of their cross-origin dumbness but I can't change the htaccess or anything where the font is stored at the moment. If anyone knows of a good cdn for demo's in jsFiddle, then please comment.

Comment: The small box is the browser’s indication of a missing glyph. Inspecting the situation in Firebug seems to show that the browser does not even request for the font file. On the other hand, `&#xe004;` denotes a Private Use codepoint and should not, as per the Unicode Standard, be used in public information interchange. To get a heavy check mark, use an image or a font containing a glyph for HEAVY CHECK MARK properly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the settings of Firefox, clock on 'advanced' and select the box where you allow sites to select their own fond.